# RabbitMQ only once getting message count from queue

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, actor

I am trying to fetch the message from the RabbitMq's queue but only first time it gives me the message count and then it is not giving me any count.I am using scala language and uses its actor.Any kind of help will be appreciated.

code as follows

```
       def act {
loop {
  FACTORY = new ConnectionFactory()
  //       println("loop")
  FACTORY.setUsername("guest")
  FACTORY.setPassword("guest")
  FACTORY.setVirtualHost("/")
  FACTORY.setPort(5672)
  FACTORY.setHost("localhost")
  **conn = FACTORY.newConnection**
  QUEUE_CHANNEL = conn.createChannel
  QUEUE_CHANNEL.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct", durable)

  var no = QUEUE_CHANNEL.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, durable,     false,false,null).getMessageCount
  println("calling to main Q" + no)
  QUEUE_CHANNEL.queueBind(QUEUE_NAME, EXCHANGE_NAME, QUEUE_ROUTING_KEY)
  if (no > 0) {
    println("calling to main Q" + no)
    getQ
  }
}
}

     def getQ {
    try {
     println("gettng main q")
  val consumer = new QueueingConsumer(QUEUE_CHANNEL)
  QUEUE_CHANNEL basicConsume (QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer)
  val delivery = consumer.nextDelivery
  val msg = new java.io.ObjectInputStream(
    new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(delivery.getBody)).readObject
  var obj = msg.asInstanceOf[QueueObject]
  QUEUE_CHANNEL.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag, false)
  //println(obj.status)
  if (obj != null)
    add(obj) //add to particular queue
} catch {
  case e: InterruptedException => println(e)
}
}
```

My code is getting into infinite loop at this line **conn = FACTORY.newConnection** when it go there second time.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the Queue as an actor? Could that be a thread that send the messages to other actors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the PO of Akka

I'd recommend you to have a look at actors in Akka, has got a slick DSL on top of AMQP that I think you could benefit from:

http://doc.akkasource.org/amqp
Another alternative is to consume the messages via Camel (if that floats your boat):

http://doc.akkasource.org/camel